# Selenium img url to text

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having trouble with selenium

I'm making a scraper for glassdoor, and I'm having trouble getting the url of the company logo

```
<span class=" job-search-key-9ujsbx euyrj9o0"><img src="https://media.glassdoor.com/sql/5130433/studs-squarelogo-1642593020221.png" alt="Studs Logo" title="Studs Logo"></span>
```

I try with xpath is not work

```
try:
                    
                logo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/section/article/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/a/span/img').link
            except NoSuchElementException:
                logo = -1
```

any help will be very valuable to me

Comment: Is element found and you get `logo = -1` or different error arise? If second please add its' description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(@class, "job-search-key")]/img').get_attribute('src')
```

Edited: as another responder mentioned, you should use get_attribute() on the resulted element, since the image url is actually an attribute of the img tag, not its actual text content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `get_attribute` method for this purpose:

```
try:
    logo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@title='Studs Logo']").get_attribute('src')
    print(logo)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: hi bro if using "title" but company logos have different titles?

Comment: I mean that is just the xpath that I have written, you can very well write your own XPath however if you want to get the attribute, you'd have to use `get_attribute('src')`